# MapView, DataFramework

Tags: android, database

i am a newbie android developper and now i'm working with Mapview. I want to show in a map differents kinds of Overlays base on his latitude and longitude.

I have created a data base with sqlite, saved on the folder assets. This is my tables.xml (sorry but the fields are in spanish)

```
<database name="loteria.db" version="1">
    <table name="puestos" to-string="%direccion%">
        <field name="direccion" type="text" obligatory="true"/>
        <field name="latitud" type="double" obligatory="false"/>
        <field name="longitud" type="double" obligatory="false"/>
    </table>
</database>
```

Is too simple. I dont need more for this moment. After thar i've created an Activity called MapaActivity where i draw my mapView. Here i have 2 problems, first one, my mapView has to be a TapControlledMapView because i want to use the method onsingleTapListener, but i cant, its caused FC always and i dont why!

The second trouble is when i want to extract from the database a list of Entitys (List

```
    List<Entity> puestos = Lists.newArrayList();
        DataFramework db = null;
        try {
            db = DataFramework.getInstance();
            db.open(this, getPackageName());
puestos = db.getEntityList("puestos", "latitud < " + maxLatitud
                    + " and latitud > " + minLatitud + " and longitud < "
                    + maxLongitud + " and longitud > " + minLongitud);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
```

Nothing happens, puestos is always empty.

Any ideas???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How come you're not just using the SQLiteOpenHelper? Check out this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

I suspect you will have better luck with it than building your tables with xml.